# Populate two level tree view by year and month in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, treeview, populate

I have a table which has two columns (year, and month) as below:

[image]

I want to populate a treeview which include years at first level and months of each year at second level.
Please guide me how to do this.

Thanks

Comment: `GroupBy` year?

Answer (score 0):

The more intuitive way is to create your hierarchy of objects in vb code, and populate your objects with the data from the table. And then you can use databinding to bind your objects to the tree view. Ex. a list of Year objects, and in each Year object, there is a list of Month objects. Once you have this hierarchy of objects, you may do the databinding in the asp.net .aspx or .ascx code.